# React Navigation 5.x Drawer Issue

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

Getting the following Issue when I use Drawer. Stack and Tab are working fine without Drawer. 
Does anyone know what is going on here and can help me?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYV81.png)

Here is Navigator File some Code lines:

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const FavStack = createStackNavigator();
const FilterStack = createStackNavigator();

const Tab =
  Platform.OS === "android"
    ? createMaterialBottomTabNavigator()
    : createBottomTabNavigator();

const defaultScreenOptions = {
  headerStyle: { backgroundColor: colors.primary },
  headerTintColor: "white",
};
function MealsNavigator() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={defaultScreenOptions}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Meals Categories" component={CategoriesScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={CategoryMealScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={MealDetailsScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

function FavStackNavigator() {
  return (
    <FavStack.Navigator screenOptions={defaultScreenOptions}>
      <FavStack.Screen name="Favourites" component={FavouritesScreen} />
      <FavStack.Screen name="Details" component={MealDetailsScreen} />
    </FavStack.Navigator>
  );
}

function MealsFavTabNavigator() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      tabBarOptions={{ activeTintColor: colors.accent }}
      shifting={true}
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="All"
        component={MealsNavigator}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: "Meals",
          tabBarIcon: (tabInfo) => (
            <Ionicons name="ios-restaurant" size={25} color={tabInfo.color} />
          ),
          tabBarColor: colors.primary,
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Favourites"
        component={FavStackNavigator}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: (tabInfo) => (
            <Ionicons name="ios-star" size={25} color={tabInfo.color} />
          ),
          tabBarColor: colors.accent,
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

function FilterStackNavigator() {
  return (
    <FilterStack.Navigator>
      <FilterStack.Screen name="Filters" component={FilterScreen} />
    </FilterStack.Navigator>
  );
}

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function MenuNavigator() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator>
      <Drawer.Screen name="MealFavs" component={MealsFavTabNavigator} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Filters" component={FilterStackNavigator} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}

export default MenuNavigator;
```

Here is App.js few Code lines:

```
export default function App() {
  const [fontLoaded, setFontLoaded] = useState(false);


  if (!fontLoaded) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={fetchFonts}
        onFinish={() => setFontLoaded(true)}
        onError={(err) => console.log(err)}
      />
    );
  }

  return <NavigationContainer><MealsNavigator /></NavigationContainer>
}
```

Code is not giving error without Drawer, It is working exactly fine with Stack and Tab Navigators!

Comment: Hey Bhavesh! It's difficult and unnecessary for an outsider to crawl through all the code you've provided. Can you give more details on what you've tried already to fix the issue and narrow the code in your question to a [reduced test case](https://webkit.org/test-case-reduction/)? (eg. exactly and only the code which causes the issue)

Comment: Upload your code to something like codepad.io so we can help you better.